# How I can add an object to a list in python?

Tags: python, qt4

```
def guardar(self):

    sAux=""

    combobox=self.ui.cmbItems.currentText()

    cantidad=str(self.ui.spinBox.value())

    subtotal=self.ui.txbSeleccion.text()

    costounidad=self.ui.txbCostoU.text()

    sAux=cantidad+"--"+combobox+" $(unidad)"+costounidad+" $(total)"+subtotal
    self.ui.textBrowser.append(sAux)
```

I want to pull the sum of the subtotal (I'm using qt4 if in doubt)

anyone know how I can do?, thanks

Comment: Where's the list you're trying to add objects to? I see a bunch of Qt widgets, and some strings, and no lists.

Comment: Also, in Python, you don't have to "declare variables at the top", like `sAux = ""`. Just create them on the fly as you need them.

Comment: @Nico, please explain what the relation is between your question and the code.

Comment: abarnet if I need to declare the variable if you get error

Comment: laszlo papp hence the question wrong what I put it as I can add an object that is in a list

Comment: I want to do is I do a acumulator to get me the sum of all subtotals for each time you call the function save

Comment: @NicoSanchez if you need an accumulater only you can use a global variable. Place it on the top of your script, for example `acc = ''` and in every function that will increase it you put `global acc`.